# Navigating with Compose not working with Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable containing a google maps view. When I click on a pin on the map I would like to trigger `navController.navigate` so I can navigate to another composable. However, when I call it the application gets stuck instead of navigating. Navigating on a button clicks works as expected.

I have also created a very simple application that is demonstrating the problem. The `MainActivity` looks like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "Screen1") {
                composable("Screen1") {
                    Button({ navController.navigate("MapsScreen") }) {
                        Text(text = "Go to Maps")
                    }
                }
                composable("MapsScreen") {
                    val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifecycle()
                    AndroidView({ mapView }) { mapView ->
                        mapView.getMapAsync { map ->
                            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener {
                                navController.navigate("Screen1")
                            }

                            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                                .position(LatLng(41.390205, 2.154007))
                                .title("Barcelona")
                            map.addMarker(markerOptions)!!
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun rememberMapViewWithLifecycle(): MapView {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context).apply {
            id = R.id.map
        }
    }

    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    DisposableEffect(lifecycle, mapView) {
        // Make MapView follow the current lifecycle
        val lifecycleObserver = getMapLifecycleObserver(mapView)
        lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        }
    }

    return mapView
}

private fun getMapLifecycleObserver(mapView: MapView): LifecycleEventObserver =
    LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> mapView.onCreate(Bundle())
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> mapView.onStart()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> mapView.onResume()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> mapView.onPause()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> mapView.onDestroy()
            else -> throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    }
```

In the project I use `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-beta02` which is the latest version at the moment according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation).

The complete project is available on [Github](https://github.com/Zlate87/compose-maps-demo)

As an inspiration for the example I have used:
[Using Google Maps in a Jetpack Compose app](https://johnoreilly.dev/posts/jetpack-compose-google-maps/) and
[Crane Sample](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Crane)

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: When the same experiment is done by adding a  android.widget.Button in the AndroidView instead of a map the navigation works, see branch button in the same repository for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like when you navigate inside the `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` method, you'll cause an deadlock.

Try to asynchronously navigate to your target to circumvent the deadlock, e.g. by using `GlobalScope.launch` on `Dispatchers.Main`, so the listener can run to the end without any deadlock:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener {
   GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
      navController.navigate("Screen1")
   }
}
```

Comment: It seams to do the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging, I come to the conclusion that the problem is somehow related to `Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()` `getMapLifecycleObserver`

Removing it solves the problem.

I'm not happy with the solution and would be happy if someone is able to provide a better solution, or at least an answer explaining more details about the problem.